# Matlab: Adding 'convolving' row and colum to make a square matrix of each element combination?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose:

```
    X = [3 1 -1 -3];
    Y = i.*X;
```

What is the simplest way to get the matrix QAM from X and Y as such:

```
QAM = [ 3+3i, 3+1i, 3-1i, 3-3i,
        1+3i, 1+1i, 1-1i, 1-3i,
       -1+3i,-1+1i,-1-1i,-1-3i,
       -3+3i,-3+1i,-3-1i,-3-3i
      ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) of course -

```
bsxfun(@plus,X(:),1i*X(:).')
```

Sample run -

```
>> X
X =
     3     1    -1    -3
>> bsxfun(@plus,X(:),1i*X(:).')
ans =
   3.0000 + 3.0000i   3.0000 + 1.0000i   3.0000 - 1.0000i   3.0000 - 3.0000i
   1.0000 + 3.0000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i   1.0000 - 1.0000i   1.0000 - 3.0000i
  -1.0000 + 3.0000i  -1.0000 + 1.0000i  -1.0000 - 1.0000i  -1.0000 - 3.0000i
  -3.0000 + 3.0000i  -3.0000 + 1.0000i  -3.0000 - 1.0000i  -3.0000 - 3.0000i
```

Answer (score 5):

I would go for [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29571134/2586922); but  an alternative is to use [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(X), 1:numel(Y));
QAM = X(ii)+Y(jj);
```

Here's a more bizarre approach, exploiting the fact that the matrix product of a column vector times a row vector generates all combinations:

```
QAM = log(exp(X(:))*exp(Y(:).'));
```

Finally, if you have the Communications Toolbox you can use [`qammod`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/qammod.html):

```
QAM = qammod(flipud(reshape(0:15,4,4)).',16);
```